# Handle Membership plans in the renewal month

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on a membership portal using `Laravel`.

Membership has different categories like 
1) Single
2) Adult
3) Family
and all types with different prices.

I have a `plans` table and `plans_subscription` table

`Plans` table has membership type information and `plans_subscription` table has the following fields

```
id | user_id | plan_id | starts_on | expires_on
```

Now the membership runs on a yearly basis and renewal for next year only opens a month before the end of the year.

I insert one row for each renewal like below

```
id | user_id | plan_id | starts_on | expires_on
1  | 23      | 1       | 01-01-2018| 31-12-2018
2  | 23      | 1       | 01-01-2019| 31-12-2019
```

Some user may decide to change the plan for the next year like following

```
id | user_id | plan_id | starts_on | expires_on
3  | 24      | 1       | 01-01-2018| 31-12-2018
4  | 24      | 2       | 01-01-2019| 31-12-2019
```

How do I show the user that they are still a member for the current year under a different plan and from next year on they will under different subscription?

How should I get the information that a user has already has paid for the next year and display get their correct membership expiry date?

Is it a good idea to insert separate rows for each renewal or should I just extend the `expires_on` date?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you need to insert seperate rows because you need to show the user what subscription he's in for next year. It's a good thing because you have a `expire_on` column. In that you can identify the subscription of the users and also you can create a block of data for the subscription history of the user if you insert seperate rows.

Comment: so db schema wise not doing anything wrong just need to improve the UI to display appropriate information.